# Best Practice for Adding an Entity with Multiple Subentities (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I currently have an object `Report`. This report object has multiple subentities, such as `WorkOrder` and `ReleaseQuestions`. I just wanted to ask the best practice for adding `WorkOrder`'s and `ReleaseQuestions`'s to the database. Currently, when a report is created, I add new blank objects to my report object, then add that to the database. This is because eventually these components will be filled out by the user, so having the blank rows sitting in the database doesn't do much harm, but I'm not sure this is the best practice. Would it be better if I added the new components separately? Or is what I'm doing not too far off?

Code, for people who are more visual:

```
public async Task<ReportModel> AddReport(ReportModel reportModel)
{
    // CapacityPlanReport report = _mapper.Map<ReportModel, CapacityPlanReport>(reportModel);

    var report = new CapacityPlanReport
    {
        AddedYear = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
        Type = reportModel.Type,
        Eta = reportModel.Eta
    };

    // Create the corresponding pieces of the report in the database.
    report.ReleaseQuestion = new CapacityPlanReleaseQuestion();
    report.WorkOrder = new CapacityPlanWorkOrder();

    _context.CapacityPlanReport.Add(report);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var result = await GetReport(report.CapacityPlanReportId);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your entity objects?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `subentities`. If you mean something like: `Employee` and then subentity `Manager`, then what you are doing is not correct because every Employee is not a Manager so it will never be filled out.

Comment: Better how? If the code works, it works. Otherwise, it's just opinions on how it should work, and opinions don't really work on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the components are going to be filled out by the user *later*, then just don't fill them at all when inserting the `Report` only and use `null`s. When the user provides you with appropriate data, create the entity, assign it to the report and `SaveChanges` - EF will  update your existing `Report` and insert the subentity into the db along with all necessary FK references.

It's probably more natural for something that does not exist yet to be `null` rather than an empty instance. An empty instance *is something* after all.